# Consuming both MULTIPART_FORM_DATA and APPLICATION_JSON in same webservice java

Tags: java, json, web-services

This is my code that saves image in directory:

```
@POST
@Path("/imagestore")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
// @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file) {     
    String dirPath = servletContext.getContextPath()+"/images";
    File imagesDir = new File(dirPath);
    boolean dirCreated = true;
    if (!imagesDir.exists()) {
        try {
            dirCreated = imagesDir.mkdirs();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
    if (dirCreated) {
        String filePath = dirPath + "/1.jpg";
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        // save the file to the server
        try {
            File newFile = new File(filePath);
            boolean fileCreated = true;
            if (!newFile.exists()) {
                fileCreated = newFile.createNewFile();
            }
            if (fileCreated) {
                FileOutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                while ((read = file.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                outpuStream.flush();
                outpuStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                obj.put("error", e.getMessage());
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String output = "File saved to server location : " + filePath;

        try {
            obj.put("output", output);
            return obj;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Now this works perfectly but i also need to save data to database and for that i need to consume Json data as well but i don't know how to do both these things are the same time because you can only write one consumes. 
In Simple words i want to consume both json (containing user info) and Mulipart_form_data (containing image to upload on server) . So how do i do it.I'll appreciate the help :)

Comment: what you trying to acheive i clear it first..

Comment: i had already cleared it but still , i have edited my answer from last part.

Comment: better to separate the both services in two independent service. like After Creating your account user enables to upload profile pic. Hope you got the flow of execution..

or Change your image in `Base64` encoded String and set this image in `json` body and decode Image String and put your file as per your need

Comment: i am gonna send data through multiple parameters instead of json and that works :)